# Take 10th Argument in batch file which runs JAR

Tags: shell, batch-file

I am trying to write a batch file, I know we can not take 10 arguments and I read about SHIFT keyword, below is what I tried but it is not working.

```
@ECHO OFF

set /A arg1 = 0


:Loop

IF "%1"=="" GOTO Continue
    set L[%arg1%] = %1
    set /A arg1 = %arg1% + 1 
    echo %arg1%
    
SHIFT

GOTO Loop

:Continue

java -jar jarApp.jar %L[0]% %L[1]% %L[2]% %L[3]% %L[4]% %L[5]% %L[6]% %L[7]% %L[8]% %L[9]%
```

But this seems to be not working, how should I modify this, thanks in advance.

//This is the argument that I wanna pass to my **batchFile.bat**

```
batchFile.bat  -action export -outputFolderPath E:\FileExtract -format json -dbserver localhost -dbcatalogue testtable
```

Comment: You should use `set "L[%arg1%]=%~1"`, not `set L[%arg1%] = %1`, _(which defines a variable named e.g. `L[0]<space>` with a value of `<space>stringvalue`)_. Doing it as you have means that there's no variables `%L[0]%`, `%L[1]%` etc. because they're actually `%L[0] %`, `%L[1] %`…

Comment: set "L[%arg1%]=%~1" with double quotes?

Comment: You should always use doublequotes to ensure that the string is protected from unwanted trailing spaces etc. The recommended syntax for defining variables is `Set "VariableName=String Value"`, _the enclosing doublequotes do not become part of the variable name or the string value and using `%~1` will remove any possible enclosing doublequotes from your argument, (you should enclose your variables with doublequotes if necessary, e.g. `"%L[3]%"`)_.

Comment: For the reason explained above, you should probably use `IF "%~1" == ""` instead of `IF "%1"==""` too. _Confusingly the trailing and leading spaces either side of the `==` operator are technically the correct syntax, (although not required), but are not considered in the comparison_. Also `set /A` is used for arithmetic, so technically as you're not performing any here `set /A arg1 = 0`, it should, more correctly, read as `set "arg1=0"`.

Comment: I am going to modify the code? Besides how I am trying to run the JAR, is it okay?

Comment: Well I cannot say, because, you've not told anyone, what exactly the command line is which is being passed to the batch file. Because of that I do not know any of the input arguments you're cycling through with your loop and `shift` are. Also, if your arguments are single strings with no problematic characters, you may find that you can use `%*`, _(for all arguments)_, in a `for` loop, to cycle through them instead. e.g. `for %%i in (%*) do …`. You may even be able to simply pass them straight to your command e.g. `java.exe -jar jarApp.jar %*`.

Comment: Based upon that edit, perhaps the last example of my previous comment will suffice, i.e. a single line batch file, `@java.exe -jar jarApp.jar %*`. Although I'm unsure why you cannot use `java.exe -jar jarApp.jar -action export -outputFolderPath E:\FileExtract -format json -dbserver localhost -dbcatalogue testtable` and forget about using a batch file altogether!

Comment: it worked! both approaches worked!

Comment: It's okay, you can have it for nothing, I'm just glad to have assisted. _In fact, if you feel this question may be of use to future readers, and you want to, you could post up your own answer, and even mark it as your accepted solution yourself._